# How can the editor color scheme in the GitLab web IDE be changed?

Tags: gitlab, web-ide

I want to use a dark theme in the GitLab web IDE, but the options related to color schemes in the user settings don't affect the editor theme. Is there currently a way to change this? If not, will it be added in a future release?

Comment: This is now (May 2020, GitLab 13.0) fully supported (dark theme for Web IDE): See my [edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384567/6309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update [GitLab 13.0, May 2020](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#dark-theme-in-the-web-ide):

> ### Dark Theme in the Web IDE

> For people who spend time working in code editors, the ability to customize the environment to match their preferences is important. Dark themes are some of the most [popular](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=Themes&sortBy=Installs) for other editors and important for providing a comfortable experience. It’s also clear that GitLab users love their dark themes as a Dark Application theme for all of GitLab is the second most popular request in the [GitLab Issue Tracker](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues?sort=popularity).
>
> The GitLab Web IDE is now completely themed dark for users who choose the **Dark** [syntax highlighting theme preference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/preferences.html#syntax-highlighting-theme).
>
> This is an important step in delivering an editing experience users love and a valuable step in understanding how the GitLab UI responds to dark themes. You can [read more about the design process here](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/05/20/creating-a-dark-ui-for-gitlabs-web-ide/index.html).
>
> See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/web_ide/#themes) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/209808).

And, still [with GitLab 13.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#syntax-highlighting-themes-for-the-web-ide):

> ### Syntax Highlighting Themes for the Web IDE

> GitLab supports six [syntax highlighting preferences](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/preferences.html#syntax-highlighting-theme) when viewing code.
>
> Themes are important to developers when viewing and editing code on GitLab since it’s imperative that they work comfortably throughout the day.
>
> **We’ve now released support for all six syntax highlighting preferences in the Web IDE**.
> This includes:
>
> - [Solarized Dark](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/201927),
> - [Solarized Light](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/201930),
> - [Monokai](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/199883) and
> - a [no highlighting option](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/216543).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_0/phikai-webide-themes.png]
>
> Over the last few releases (for example, 12.8 and 12.9) we’ve been steadily adding and improving support for syntax highlighting preferences in the Web IDE.
> These updates follow this effort and help to lay the foundation for our Dark Theme in the Web IDE, also launching in 13.0.
> We’re excited to continue to expand on developer experience and making the Web IDE feel more like home.
>
> Over the last few releases (for example, [12.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/02/22/gitlab-12-8-released/#dark-syntax-highlighting-theme-for-web-ide) and [12.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/03/22/gitlab-12-9-released/#white-syntax-highlighting-theme-for-web-ide)) we’ve been steadily adding and improving support for syntax highlighting preferences in the Web IDE. These updates follow this effort and help to lay the foundation for our [Dark Theme in the Web IDE](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#dark-theme-in-the-web-ide), also launching in 13.0. We’re excited to continue to expand on developer experience and making the Web IDE feel more like home.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/web_ide/#themes) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/2389).

---

Original answer:

> If not, will it be added in a future release?

Feb. 2020 might be that future release date, with GitLab 12.8

See "[Dark syntax highlighting theme for Web IDE](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/02/22/gitlab-12-8-released/#dark-syntax-highlighting-theme-for-web-ide)"

> GitLab has long supported alternative [syntax highlighting themes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/preferences.html#syntax-highlighting-theme) for use when browsing files in the repository or viewing diffs during the code review process.
>
> However, our code editor areas have not supported the use of this preference despite being the most requested feature for the Web IDE.
> ([issue 195701](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/195701))
>
> **The Web IDE now supports the Dark syntax highlighting preference in the code area**.
> We’ve started with this theme, as it’s the most widely used one beyond our default, but we’ll continue to expand our support for syntax highlighting preferences on the Web IDE.
>
> We’ll also be working on expanding the dark theme to the rest of the Web IDE, including the file tree and sidebars.
>
> [image: dark Web IDE -- https://about.gitlab.com/images/12_8/phikai-dark-syntax-webide.png]

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/preferences.html#syntax-highlighting-theme).

---

With [GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#default-syntax-highlighting-theme-for-new-users) (March 2023)

> ### Default syntax highlighting theme for new users
>
> Set the syntax highlighting theme shown to new users, or users who are viewing code but not signed in.
>
> Previously, the default only applied to signed-in users, causing signed-out users to sometimes see a visual clash between dark and light theme highlighting.
>
> Thank you [Colin Berry](https://github.com/colin969) for your contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/preferences.html#syntax-highlighting-theme) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/25129).

Answer (score 0):

For now only `Navigation` and `Syntax` theme customizations are available, as stated in here: [GitLab IDE](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/preferences.html)

I don't think there is anything about customizations in upcoming patches, as new UI was presented about year ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like Stylish for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/). This is the dark theme that I use [Dark-Gitlab](https://userstyles.org/styles/164877/dark-gitlab).

This will alter how GitLab appears in your browser.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out.